# Is there a double power switch that guarantees that whenever A is on then B is on too (with slight time margin for safety)?

Tags: power

I want to completely cut power to a solar charging setup sometimes, to prevent even the background power draw of the solar charge controller itself from consuming battery charge.

Charge controllers are apparently sensitive to when the solar panel is connected but the battery isn't, so I always have to be careful to disconnect the solar panel before the battery, and to always connect the battery before the solar panel.

It would be easier if there were one switch that for both off and on, the circuits are closed and opened in the right order.

Note that if there's some time, probably in milliseconds but preferably less than one second, between the steps that would be best, to let the solar charge controller boot up before the solar panel power comes in.

For my current use case I'm looking at being able to handle up to about 10A.

Is there a name for such a thing?

Comment: How much current?

Comment: Sometimes a device called a "sequencer" (not a music sequencer!) is used to perform this sort of task.  People (radio hams) who construct a sophisticated series of devices (IF radio, transverter, PA, LNA, T/R switch) employ one.  Of course, the current levels are nowhere near those of a solar system.

Comment: @HandyHowie 10A for my current project at least. (I've also edited the question with this info)

Comment: I’d call it “the thing you have to design”.

Comment: @Andyaka that may be. I could probably 3D print a switch that would first close one circuit and then another. Just seems to me that it should exist already.

Comment: @Thomas I wouldn't recommend doing that. You will have a hard time getting it to work reliably, let alone withstand 10A.

Comment: Have you looked at how much current the charge controller draws in sleep mode? Leaving it on may not draw a significant amount of power.

Comment: @CalebReister It's not a lot in the double-digit mA range. Still, that I'm estimating that'll add up to a noticeable amount charge time in the winter just to keep it running overnight. But yeah very likely I'm missing much lower hanging fruit. Oh well, if it were just a simple switch I could get then it would be worth it, now I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably not switches that will do this, all DPDT switches that I have seen work at the same time. You might be able to use a circuit like this with a high side switch:

[image]
[Default-on, latch-off, MOSFET power switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67425/default-on-latch-off-mosfet-power-switch)

The problem with doing so is when the solar panel voltage dropped it would also disconnect the battery. The best thing would probably be to use a DPDT switch to disconnect both at the same time, to add a delay you might place a large cap on the battery side between the switch and the controller.

Comment: Another option might be to drive a couple of relays using a microcontroller (or even a 555 timer for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

An ON - OFF - ON switch with two changeover contacts will do the job.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyc6Wz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Wiring of the switch results in left to right switching action of A being switched on first and remaining on when B is switched.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The switch may look something like this.*

Make sure the contacts are adequately rated for your load at DC.

Regarding the time margin for safety, a clear instruction on the switch to move once, wait a second and move again should be adequate.

Comment: This doesn't look like it'll allow switching two independent circuits though, does it?

Comment: See my use of "like" in the Figure 2 caption. Why do you think it wouldn't allow switching of two independent circuits? The COM wiring is mine. You'd be looking for independent contacts and then you can do as you please.